# Scala Replacement for Akka Transactors

Tags: scala, akka, actor, stm

In version 2.3 Akka [dropped support for transactors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/project/migration-guide-2.2.x-2.3.x.html).

A quote from [Akka's 2.0 documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/transactors.html) about transactors:

> When you really need composable message flows across many actors updating their internal local state but need them to do that atomically in one big transaction. Might not be often but when you do need this then you are screwed without it.

What is the best way to manage STM transactions across multiple actors in the absence of transactors?

Is it a [bad idea](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/05/STM-Dropped) using STM in the first place?

Comment: It sounds to me like they dropped transactors because the whole concept of STM goes against what they're trying to do with actors - actors make scaling great because they don't need to share state, but to make use of them, it requires you to restructure your programs in a way that this can work.  I suspect that they meant for transactors to be used extremely infrequently, but people used them liberally and then wondered why they weren't getting the performance they thought akka should give them.

Comment: @soong This is probably correct, although its a little frustrating that they dropped a feature which by their own admission "you are screwed without".